# Cannot receive VoIP messages in background/suspended state in iOS 13 Devices

Tags: apple-push-notifications, chat, voip, ios13

I am developing a chatting application. To enhance the message delivery experience, I was using VoIP push to deliver messages to the application in the background/killed state. This is just how whatsapp does this, I guess. It was working fine on devices with iOS version prior to 13.0. However, on iOS 13 devices the push is only coming in the foreground state. In the background state, I could not get callback in `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` delegate method. I have gone through few online blogs where it's been written that apple restricted it to only use for the calling purposes now. One more thing that people proposed was that if the app is distributed over XCode 10 i.e, compiled with iOS 12 SDK then also it should work. However, It is not working in my case no matter what XCode I used. My objective is to deliver the messages to the users even when the application is killed/in background just like whatsapp. Any thoughts/guidance over this is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was facing your exact same issue; the problem for me was that on iOS 13 there is a new pushkit delegate method:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void
```

it differs from the previous one (now deprecated) for the completion handler at the end of the prototype.
Documentation states that you **must** call the completion handler (even if void) to tell CallKit that the call has been handled.
Failing to comply will then *ban* your app from receiving pushkit notification when in background or force-quit states. It still works while app is in foreground.

I solved adding to my app the following code:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        NSLog("Got new callback incoming notification")
        self.pushRegistry(registry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith: payload, for: type)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion()
        }
    }
```

P.S. To clear the *banned* status (that is triggered after 2-3 compliancy failures in my tests) you need to completely delete the app from the device and start over.

Comment: Hi @alienpenguin, I did it as you said. Now I can receive the notification in background but the application gets crashed. And after 3-4 times, push also stops coming. Please also tell me "self.pushRegistry(registry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith: payload, for: type)" this method you're calling. When i try to call it, it gives error.

Comment: In the callback you *must* call reportNewIncomingCall and tell callkit that a new call is arriving. If you fail to do this the app will crash and after a few times it will not receive push notifications again, until you re-install it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CallKit in iOS 13.

> For apps built using the iOS 13 SDK or later, PushKit requires you to use CallKit when handling VoIP calls. CallKit ensures that apps providing call-related services on a user’s device work seamlessly together on the user's device, and respect features like Do Not Disturb

also

> If you are unable to support CallKit in your app, you cannot use PushKit to handle push notifications. Instead, configure your app's push notification support with the UserNotifications framework.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit)

Comment: thanks for your reply. However my question is a bit different. I am using Callkit & PushKit for Audio/Video Calls and it is working fine. But I was also using Pushkit for delivering instant messages in the background/killed state. That stops working on iOS 13. I just need to know if somehow I can still exploit Pushkit ability or use something else to deliver messages in background.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know any other way other than UserNotification. But  I think that will be user-facing and won't be totally background.

Answer (score 1):

In general the VoIP implementation contains the following steps:

1. Adding a VoIP capability
2. Register voip-Pushes:

```
private func registerForVoIPPushes() {
   voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
   voipRegistry?.delegate = self
   voipRegistry?.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
}
```

3. Implementation of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

4. Offcourse server side part implementation
5. **! The most often issue:**
   Once the app got voIP notification and not reported it to CXProvider object it won't get notifications anymore until you reinstall it. So, be sure of reporting every voIP you get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use Notification content extension for it. 
We can tell our messaging server that the message has been delivered.
We can also share the local database between main application and content extension, if we need.
We can fetch actual message from server if we are delivering actual message in APNS.
Notification Content Extension will give around 30 seconds window to sync the data.

Comment: what if the app was killed? is it still working for you?

Comment: Yes, extension gets called event when the main application is in background or killed state. We can tell server that the message has been delivered from extension.